# Strange Flutter Error : platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner`

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I created a clean new project with Flutter 2.10.3.

Flutter doctor: everything is green, no issue.

I successfully build and run the project with this ios device. Then, I try to run on MacOS once. now both iOS and MacOS selection are not able to run with below strange message.

I try this as well but no luck: [Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68781785/automatically-assigning-platform-ios-with-version-9-0-on-target-runner-bec)

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              3.3s
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform
was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See
`https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009):
tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an
incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')) -
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in
    `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in
    `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in
    `download_file_async'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in
    `download_file'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in
    `refresh_metadata'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in
    `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in
    `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in
    `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in
    `block in source_from_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in
    `source_from_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in
    `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in
    `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in
    `aggregate_with_repos'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in
    `aggregate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in
    `all'
    from
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in
    `repo_information'
    from
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in
    `stack'
    from
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in
    `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError)
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in
    `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in
    `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in
    `download_file_async'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in
    `download_file'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in
    `refresh_metadata'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in
    `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in
    `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in
    `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in
    `block in source_from_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in
    `source_from_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in
    `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in
    `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in
    `aggregate_with_repos'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in
    `aggregate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in
    `all'
    from
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in
    `repo_information'
    from
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in
    `stack'
    from
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in
    `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009):
tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an
incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')) -
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in
    `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in
    `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in
    `download_file_async'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in
    `download_file'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in
    `refresh_metadata'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in
    `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in
    `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in
    `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in
    `block in source_from_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in
    `source_from_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in
    `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in
    `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in
    `aggregate_with_repos'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in
    `aggregate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in
    `all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in
    `source_with_url'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in
    `find_or_create_source_with_url'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block
    in sources'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in
    `sources'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in
    `block in resolve_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in
    `resolve_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in
    `analyze'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in
    resolve_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in
    `resolve_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError)
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
    quire.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in
    `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in
    `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in
    `download_file_async'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in
    `download_file'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in
    `refresh_metadata'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in
    `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in
    `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in
    `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in
    `block in source_from_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in
    `source_from_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in
    `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in
    `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in
    `aggregate_with_repos'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in
    `aggregate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in
    `all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in
    `source_with_url'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in
    `find_or_create_source_with_url'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block
    in sources'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in
    `sources'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in
    `block in resolve_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in
    `resolve_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in
    `analyze'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in
    resolve_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in
    `resolve_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).

Comment: Are you using m1 mac by any chance?

Comment: yes. I am using on M1 Air

Comment: can you try running `arch -x86_64 pod install` instead of just `pod install`?

Comment: @SoumyaMahunt . it is producing the same error. I was working fine. this is strange. I can run Web and Android. with no issue

Answer (score 1):

got the same issue on MacBook m1
try this:

**$ arch -x86_64 pod install**

Comment: thank you. not really sure, but this helps. one thing, i do is i try to reinstall gem.