# Flutter app cannot be launched in iOS simulator due to missing platform specification

Tags: ios, flutter, podfile

I am getting error, while trying to run main.dart file on iOS simulator

> Error output from CocoaPods:
> ↳
> [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `11.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
> Error running pod install
> Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
> Exited

I uncommented line with thr platform specification in my Podfile, but error persists:

```
     Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
     platform :ios, '9.0'

     flutter_application_path = '../flutter_module_books/'
     load File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')

     target 'IosBooks' do
     # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
     use_frameworks!
     # Pods for IosBooks
     install_all_flutter_pods(flutter_application_path)
     end

     post_install do |installer|
     flutter_post_install(installer) if defined?(flutter_post_install)
     end
```

Comment: I had the same issue after upgrading flutter version, and resolved it by running `pod update` in the `ios` directory. This has happened in previous flutter version updates as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68781785/automatically-assigning-platform-ios-with-version-9-0-on-target-runner-bec